# Using AWK to compare values in the same column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I'm using AWK and I've been trying to compare the previous value in a column with the next one until it finds the highest but I haven't been able to.

```
awk '$6 >= $6 {print $6}'
```

With the above, it returns me every single value

For example:

```
money:
49
90
30
900
```

I would like it to return 900

Comment: In general, `x >= x` is true for any x.  I don' see the purpose of this expression. From your description, you simply want to find the maximum number in this column. Think of how you would find the maximum number in an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this:

```
awk 'int($6) && $6 > n{n=$6}END{print n}' file
```

Comment: if things like "5999E999" show up in the input,  without gawk -M, it may output errorneously. Make it 2 rows "5999E999\n999." and it's the "999." that prints

Comment: That would fail and print a null string if the largest value in the input was `0`.

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk '(NR>1) && ((NR==2) || ($1>max)){max=$1} END{if (max != "") print max}' file
900
```

The above is based on your posted example (including the `money:` header line) but would also work even if all input values were `0` or negative or the input file was empty. Change `$1` to `$6` if the real field number you're interested in is 6.

Also consider:

```
$ tail -n +2 file | cut -f1 | sort -rn | head -1
900
```

and change `-f1` to `-f6`.

Set separator chars in awk with `-F'<char>'` and cut with `-d'<char>'` if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the columns are separated by the default (white-space) separator, the following awk line checks the 6th value in each data row to see if it is greater than any previously seen values (`current` set in a `BEGIN` block to zero, gets updated each time a greater 6th value is encountered). The `END` block prints the final value held in `current` (which is the greatest value for the 6th field)"

```
awk 'BEGIN {current=0} NR>1{if ($6>current) current=$6} END {print current}' dataFile.txt
```

For `.csv` data, the file separator can be defined as a comma with `FS=","` in the `BEGIN` block:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","; current=0} NR>1{if ($6>current) current=$6} END {print current}' dataFile.csv
```

Comment: That would fail if all input values were negative. Always seed min/max variables with the first value read, not some arbitrary number that you hope will be large/smaller than the values in the input.

Comment: Also, you should restrict the selection to numeric columns. According to the OP, there is at least one entry which is not a number, but the word _Money_, and you have to exclude such entries.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ awk 'NR==2  {max=$6} 
       $6>max {max=$6} 
       END    {print max}' file
```